# IntelliJ Community 12 CE + JFlex

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, jflex

I'm following [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Custom+Language+Support) tutorial to create a custom language plugin for *IntelliJ 12*, but I'm running into several issues in regards to the *jFlex plugin*.

When the plugin was installed (via IntelliJ plugin browser) it was configured with the following paths:

- Flex: `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE.app/tools/jflex`
- Flex Skeleton: `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE.app/tools/jflex/idea-flex.skeleton`

IntelliJ warned me it could not find the jFlex application, so I downloaded the latest `zip` package from jflex.de and extracted it. I updated the jFlex plugin configurations in IntelliJ and get a new error when I try to build: `./lib/jflex.jar` is not configured on the path.

- Flex: `/Users/skyler/jflex-1.4.3/jflex-1.4.3/bin`
- Flex Skeleton: `/Users/skyler/jflex-1.4.3/jflex-1.4.3/src/default.skeleton`

I did confirm the jar exists in `/Users/skyler/jflex-1.4.3/jflex-1.4.3/lib`. Of course the path referenced in the error would not find the jar.

**So here are my questions:**

1. Where is the `idea-flex.skeleton` file located? I cannot find it.
2. Do I need to update the *jflex* executable so the paths are correct, or move the file, and will there be any problems using *jflex* for language plugin development with this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out IntelliJ was missing the tools directory when you use the Mac installer. To solve the problem I had to clone the git repository for IntelliJ community and copy the jflex folder and skeleton into the expected locations. This issue is tracked by JetBrains.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110168